# How to include ReactiveCocoa 3.0 in Xcode 7 project

Tags: xcode, git, swift2

I have a swift 2.0 project in xcode 7 beta 5 and want to use ReactiveCocoa 3.0.

I have been able to setup a project for xcode 6.3 and swift 1.2 but can not figure out how to do it for xcode 7 and swift2

There is a swift2 branch but every method I've found just calls in the main branch.

Clear step by step instructions would be really great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit
IMPORTANT: you need carthage 0.8.0 at least!!! And don't forget to choose Xcode 7 build tools via `xcode-select`

---

1. Install carthage via `brew install carthage`
2. If homebrew is not installed look at http://brew.sh
3. Create a file called `Cartfile` in the directory where your Xcode project file lives
4. As content of the `Cartfile` add the following line:
   `github "ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa" "swift2"`
5. Launch Terminal.app. cd into this folder and run:
   `carthage update`
   This will build .framework files in a `Carthage/Build` folder
6. Inside the build folder you will find two frameworks:
   `ReactiveCocoa.framework` and `Result.framework` (inside iOS/OSX/WatchOS folder)
7. Drag both of these files into the **Embedded Binaries** section of your Xcode Project file's **General** tab
8. Build and run!

Comment: if you are using 10.11 beta brew cannot be run as normal... /usr/local/ cannot be used by brew. There is a workaround though

Comment: Thanks. I also needed to make sure carthage used the right version of xcode:     `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: Oh yes, this is important, too. Xcode 7 command line tools should be used

Comment: I think adding Jim T's comment to the answer would be wise.  It didn't work without it.  I guess you kind of did, but I didn't know what you meant.  Perhaps if you could have the explicit call.

Comment: `carthage update` failed for me with a `Failed to discover shared schemes in project Result.xcodeproj`... error. Worked around it (for an iOS only build) by running `carthage update --platform iOS`.